# How to deal with python3 multiprocessing in __main__.py

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-module

Il posed question, I did not understand the ture cause of the issue (it seems to have been related to my usage of flask in one of the subprocesses).

PLEASE IGNORE THIS (can't delete due to bounty)

Essentially, I have to start some Processes and or a pool when running a python library as a module.

However, since `__name__ == '__main__'` is always true in `__main__.py` this proves to be an issue (see multiprocessing docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

I've attempted multiple solutions ranging from: pytgquabr.com:8182/58288945/using-multiprocessing-with-runpy to a file-based mutext to only allow the contents of **main** to run once but multiprocessing still behaves strangely (e.g. Processes die almost as soon as they start with no error logs).

Any idea of what the "proper" way of going about this is ?

Comment: Why do you have a file called `__main__.py`?

Comment: In order to run the library as a module (i.e. using `python -m my_lib_name` when it is installed via pip)

Comment: Even if your file was called `my_lib_name.py` and you ran it with `python -m my_lib_name`, the `__name__` variable in your script would be set to `__main__`

Comment: Note that I said library (though maybe it makes more sense if I say package) I.e. I want people installing via pip to run it this way. You approach, I believe, doesn't work for this. See the official python docs on the subject: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: Have you tried it? Can you provide a verifiable example?

Comment: Yes, of course, I have. You can try it yourself by adding a project to your PYPATH and using python -m project_name with and without the __main__.py file, the behavior will be different (i.e. it will fail in the first case).

Comment: Have you read the documentation page I provided? I believe you might be misunderstanding the issue here

Comment: Is the issue on windows or Linux or both? What is the layout of your package (has an __init__, many submodules, does __main__.py load those submodules)? Where and how is the Pool started?  Adding a reproducible example would answer most of these questions.

Comment: Will try to add one as soon as I have time, I thought this issue might be "standard" rather than an edge case related to a werid structure in my modules. However I don't have a `main.py` file I have a `__main__.py`, that's the whole problem here. If my file was named `main.py` I could just check `__name__ == '__main__'` and the issue would be resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guarding the `__main__` module is only needed if an object *defined* inside `__main__` is used in another process. Looking up this definition is what causes the execution of `__main__` in the subprocess.

When using a `__main__.py`, restrict all definitions used with `multiprocessing` to other modules. `__main__.py` should only import and use these.

```
# my_package/some_module.py
def module_print(*args, **kwargs):
    """Function defined in some module - fine for use inside multiprocess"""
    print(*args, **kwargs)

# my_package/__main__.py
import multiprocessing                 # imports are allowed
from .some_module import module_print

def do_multiprocess():
    """Function defined in __main__ module - fine for use wrapping multiprocess"""
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12) as pool:
        pool.map(module_print, range(20))  # multiprocessing external function is allowed

do_multiprocess()  # directly calling __main__ function is allowed
```